# I have the flask server listening but nothing shows up when its called by js

Tags: javascript, python, ubuntu, flask

I have a js file calling an api using this line: fetch('http://localhost:4243/get-states')

Then i have the python flask server listening and it says:
2023-08-31 16:39:27,426 - INFO - [31m[1mWARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m

- Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:4243
- Running on http://144.202.80.231:4243
  2023-08-31 16:39:27,427 - INFO - [33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
  2023-08-31 16:39:27,457 - INFO -  * Restarting with watchdog (inotify)
  2023-08-31 16:39:27,791 - WARNING -  * Debugger is active!
  2023-08-31 16:39:27,796 - INFO -  * Debugger PIN: 411-163-394

When i call it, it does nothing.
no new line in the .log file showing the request.

its not the firewall. Ive allowed it on 4243

Ive tried getting it to call this python function but its just not working. what do i do? what else is there to try?

Comment: Also, im getting a lot of junk from InotifyEvent that i dont understand. Im talking about 10's of thousand of lines that all say:
2023-08-31 16:45:12,598 - DEBUG - in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/home/ubuntu/stripe_checkout/state_info_server.log', wd=1, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name=state_info_server.log>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you checked the developer console? Open it and head to the network tab. It'll show you any requests the page makes so you'll be able to track from the frontend when or if the request is sent along with the various details about the request.

Second, make sure the request is actually being sent. Check for any errors on the frontend with the developer console, because there's a high probability that the JS code isn't sending the request in the first place. This could likely be due to an error with the code itself or invalid data being passed into the request, to which JS won't send it. I'd check it for you here but you haven't provided any code which makes it hard for me to troubleshoot anything.

Third, verify the server is actually running correctly on port 4243. Just go to it in your browser and make sure it's showing proper output. It could be an issue with the port you're using, I've had issues like that where certain ports don't run correctly, so if this is the case try running on a different port like 5000.